# localhost within docker user defined network?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I've started two docker containers on a user defined docker network. It appears that in order to have one connect to the exported port of the other, I need to address the container-name of that other container, *as if it were the host name*, thus relying on the underlying docker embedded DNS feature [as per one of the options here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/). Addressing `localhost` does not seem to work.

Using a user defined network (which I gather is the recommended way now to communicate between containers), is it really the case that `localhost` would not work?

Or is there an alternative and standard way for making docker assume that the containers on the network are simply on a single host, thus making `localhost` resolve in the user-defined-network as it would on a regular non-virtualized host?

Comment: How do you propose containers resolve port mappings if they are all on the same host?

Comment: Port mapping isn't really a mandatory requirement on the same host inside a virtual network. And as far as I care, containers could make their port mappings towards the virtual network. But this discussion is a little off topic.

Comment: Question is also applicable to docker-compose default networks, which are (currently) always on the same host as far as I can tell.